# Can I buy Visual Studio 2013 ULTIMATE without MSDN?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

As our projects are growing very fast, we are interested in features of Visual Studio 2013 like Profiling and IntelliTrace, which our current IDE (Visual Studio 2008 standard) can not offer.

However, we are not interested in a MSDN subscription. According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Editions_feature_grid

we need the **ultimate** edition.

According to this link (which was already hard to find)

http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/mseea/en_US/list/VisualStudio/parentCategoryID.66235500/categoryID.66235600

the **ultimate** edition is only available with MSDN.

Does "MSDN integration == full" of the first link imply that vs 2013 ultimate is **only** available with a MSDN subscription?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only VS Professional is available with or without MSDN, all other versions include a MSDN subscription

Comment: I would also think that there should be no reason not to get MSDN subscriptions.  Buy a subscription, download the software, use the provided key and just don't use all of the other benefits.

Comment: @HeXanon I agree. Also MSDN universal includes other benefits, like access to Office, Windows and almost any other MS software (just for development, not for production); it also includes a monthly credit for Azure

Comment: I'm concerned about the pricing. While vs 2013 Professional starts at 625 EUR without MSDN, it sets you back 1.502 EUR **with** MSDN. The **ultimate** edition is starting at > 16k EUR for a **new** MSDN subscription, so I hoped a non-MSDN version could save us some cash.

Comment: @duddel Yes, the price is high, but you can make your customers pay for it ;)

Comment: We've made do with Premium (Intellitrace looks great but at 10+ seats in a small dev shop it isn't worth 2K EUR to us).  The 3.5K for Premium with MSDN isn't even a decision.  As @Loghorn highlighted, add in Windows, SQL Server, Office for your dev workstations and server as well as TFS it's an absolute bargain.  Is intellitrace worth 2K EUR - that is the question you need to ask.

Comment: I don't think it exists directly. But I badly needed it for my contract and bought it for myself from a this [third-party supplier](http://www.danarou.com/giftshop2.asp?go=Buy-Visual-Studio-Without-MSDN&buy=VSP13,VSU13). I don't think anybody else sells it, so I am glad somebody does...

Comment: @SashaGlover - Is that site legitimate? How is Microsoft allowing him to sell their software so cheaply?